# Pandoc - is tex output with dollar sign math possible?

Tags: pandoc

Is it possible to have `.tex` files **output** from pandoc have math mode with dollar signs (`$`)? The [manual](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math) says:

**LaTeX:** It will appear verbatim surrounded by **\(...\)** (for inline math) or **\[...\]** (for display math).

I also found this [Github issue](https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/2614) from 2016 where the author says it could be selectable. Is there now a pandoc argument or another way of having the `.tex` output use dollar signs?

Comment: jep, still the case https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#math

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this using a pandoc filter. E.g.:

```lua
-- Do nothing unless we are targeting TeX.
if not FORMAT:match('tex$') then return {} end

function Math (m)
  local delimiter = m.mathtype == 'InlineMath' and '$' or '$$'
  return pandoc.RawInline('tex', delimiter .. m.text .. delimiter)
end
```

Save to file `dollar-math.lua`, and pass it to pandoc via `--lua-filter=dollar-math.lua`.

Comment: Works perfectly!